# sending texts messages to my own cell number and it always dupicates it why

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I sometimes send text messages to myself in the form of pictures, and it always sends me them in duplicate. one on the right and on the left hand side of my screen. does anyone know why my phone would do this?

Answer (score 6):

You send one message (it's on the right side) and you recieve one (it's on the left side).

Comment: Probably the best, yet simple explanation I have read in a while